# Keyboard input hides new entry in the recycleview adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using a recycleview to display latest inputs from the user. When I click edit text, the old inputs move up and the keyboard shows in the app. But when I enter the next entry, I have to minimize the keyboard to be able to see the new entry. It doesnt move up - this was expected behaviour as the recycleview is updated.

Stage 1)

- Old Entry
- Old Entry

Stage 2) Click edit text to make new entry

- Old Entry
- Old Entry
- Keyboard

Stage 3) New text is entered

- Old Entry
- Old Entry
- Keyboard

Stage 4) Keyboard is hidden,/minimized

- Old Entry
- Old Entry
- New Entry

The layout is stacked from the end... what can I change to make this work?

AndroidManifest setting

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Contacts.ui.ContactDetailsHome"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

fragment code

```
class ContactRelationship : Fragment() {

companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    fun start(context: Context, contact: Contact?, isEdit: Boolean) {
        val starter = Intent(context, ContactRelationship::class.java)
            .putExtra("contact", contact as Serializable)
            .putExtra("Edit", isEdit)
        context.startActivity(starter)
    }
}

private val _updatesLiveData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<ContUPDt>>()
private val updatesLiveData: LiveData<ArrayList<ContUPDt>> = _updatesLiveData
var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null //the used id of the user using the app
var userLookupKey: String = ""
private lateinit var contact: Contact
var mupdateList: List<ContUPDt>? = null
var contUpdateAdapter: ContUpdateAdapter? = null
var reference: DatabaseReference? = null
lateinit var rvContRelUpdate: RecyclerView
private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressDialog

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view: View =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_contact_relationship, container, false)

    progressBar = ProgressDialog(activity)
    progressBar.setCancelable(false)
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    rvContRelUpdate = view.findViewById(R.id.rvContRelUpdate)
    rvContRelUpdate.setHasFixedSize(true)
    val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    linearLayoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
    rvContRelUpdate.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    contact = (activity?.intent?.getSerializableExtra("contact") as Contact)
    //assigning it to fields to be displayed
    userLookupKey = contact.lookupKey
    val contId = contact.id

    //get updates
    retrieveUpdates(userLookupKey)

    //Implementing Send Update
    send_update_btn.setOnClickListener {
        val updateTxt = text_messageact.text.toString()
        if (updateTxt == "") {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "The update is empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        } else {
            sendMessageToUser(userLookupKey, contId, updateTxt)
        }
        text_messageact.setText("")
    }

private fun sendMessageToUser(userLookupKey: String, contId: String, updateMsg: String) {

    val currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    //creating object in DB
    val db = activity?.let { AppDatabase.getDatabase(it) }
    val ev = ContUPDt(
        0,
        userLookupKey,
        contId,
        currentCalendar.timeInMillis,
        updateMsg,
        null,
        "Update"
    )
    db!!.ContUpdateDao().addcontUpdate(ev)
}

private fun retrieveUpdates(userLookupKey: String) {

    val mupdateList = ArrayList<ContUPDt>()
    val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(requireActivity())
    db.ContUpdateDao().getcontUpdate(userLookupKey).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        val contUpdt = it
        mupdateList.clear()
        for (i in contUpdt) {
            mupdateList.add(i)
        }
    })
    contUpdateAdapter = ContUpdateAdapter(requireActivity(), mupdateList)
    rvContRelUpdate.adapter = contUpdateAdapter
}
```

}

Adapter code

```
class ContUpdateAdapter(
mContext: Context,
    mupdateList: List<ContUPDt>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ContUpdateAdapter.ViewHolder?>() {
    private val mContext: Context
    private val mupdateList: List<ContUPDt>

init {
    this.mContext = mContext
    this.mupdateList = mupdateList
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var updateDTTime: TextView? = null
    var updateMessage: TextView? = null
    var updateType: TextView? = null

    init {
        updateDTTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.updateDTTime)
        updateMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.updateMessage)
        updateType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.updateType)
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    position: Int
): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder (
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.contactupdate, parent, false)
    )
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val contUpdte: ContUPDt = mupdateList[position]
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(" E, HH:MM a, dd MMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
    val updatetime = formatter.format(contUpdte.timestamp)

    holder.updateDTTime!!.text = updatetime
    holder.updateMessage!!.text = contUpdte.update
    holder.updateType!!.text = contUpdte.actType
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mupdateList.size
}
```

}

Comment: Try changing `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to `adjustPan` instead. That should fix it most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just scroll RecyclerView to last position after adding new item:
`rvContRelUpdate.scrollToPosition(contUpdateAdapter.itemCount - 1)`

Comment: This works only sometimes! and on some devices it doesnt work at all! cant understand the issue...